# How can I replenish my health?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

I am pretty early on in the game and I'm low health (I can hear a heartbeat).

What methods are there are replenishing my health in Sleeping Dogs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are out of combat, your health will regenerate back up to 50%.

Additionally, various vendors throughout the world will have a "..." symbol above their heads, these vendors sell a variety of items, including food and drink (or in the case below; ice cream):

[image] [image]